# Ionic 5 - chrome://inspect do not see webpack folder

Tags: cordova, debugging, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I have an Ionic 5 app with Angular 12 and Cordova. I use the following for live reload:

```
ionic cordova run android -l
```

I am not sure what has happened but when I now launch chrome://inpsect, click inspect, and go to Sources tab to debug my code, I no longer have the webpack:// folder. This has worked before.

I see **top\localhost:8100\plugin**, **top\localhost:8100\connection**, and **top\localhost:8100\minimized js** files but no **webpack://** folder.

I have tried removing the platforms and adding them back. I have also removed the existing www folder and adding an empty www folder back.

Below is my Ionic info.

Any ideas as to what might have changed to cause this and what I need to do to get the webpack:// folder back?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/Users/b/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.9
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v14.17.1 (/Users/b/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.13
   OS      : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode   : Xcode 12.5.1 Build version 12E507
```

Thanks,

Brent

Comment: And what are the versions of OS on the device and version of the browser? Is if possible that browser is out of date in terms of syncing with Android OS?

Comment: I am using a Pixel running Android 10 with Chrome version 91.0.4472.120. I do see that chrome://inspect shows they are out of sync, but in the past if I used the inspect fallback link it would work. It no longer does. If I create a brand new starter project (Ionic 5 / Angular 12) I can see the webpack:// folder so something is now wrong with my app's project. Just not sure how to track it down?

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried a number of things.

To get it to work I ended up creating a new Ionic 5 project and then adding my components, pages, etc.